# discord.js - fetchMessage doesn't give a valid output

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Trying to make an application response system for my Discord that takes information from a pre-set Discord message in the same server. Currently it spits out an error stating that it can not send an empty message: **"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"**

(The fetchMessage must be saved to a variable for later editing)

```
        if (message.content == '/results') {
            let ttpResultsChannel = client.channels.get("662034469708103690")
            var temp
            ttpResultsChannel.fetchMessage('662034597508546582').then(results => temp = results.content)
            message.channel.send(temp)
        }
```

This is the text it should output:

```
179654608371712000{}PASSED{}TestText1{}
514127283636797450{}FAILED{}TextTest6{}
```

I'm new to the JavaScript world and probably my error is pretty simple but this is one of the times that I couldn't find the solution myself. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you're trying to send an empty message, which makes sense since `fetchMessage` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You properly use `.then()` to get the result, however by the time that Promise has resolved and you've gotten your result and assigned it to `temp`, `message.channel.send()` has already been executed. To fix it, you just have to put the sending inside the `.then()`:

```js
if (message.content == '/results') {
    let ttpResultsChannel = client.channels.get("662034469708103690")
    var temp
    ttpResultsChannel.fetchMessage('662034597508546582')
        .then(results => {
            temp = results.content
            message.channel.send(temp)
        })
}
```

Comment: In some cases this actually won't resolve the error. For example, if the message contains a rich embed or attachment and no actual content, the API will return the same error.